# Uninstalled software keeps coming back

Tags: software-installation, software-center, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall software i'm never going to use (including firefox, rhythmbox, imagemagick, vim and others i have alternative programm for). I tried to uninstall these programs via both Ubuntu software centre and synaptic package manager but uninstalled software keeps getting installed back. Does someone know how to uninstall these programs once for all?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `zgrep -C 1 -F -e firefox -e rhythmbox -e imagemagick -e vim /var/log/apt/history.log*` (add more affected package names if you wish)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can List Installed Packages
Open terminal:

> sudo su

(will give you root permissions)

> apt list --installed

(Shows all installed apps)
Now here is a trick

> apt-get purge

removes configuration files, 
while

> apt-get remove

does not!

So you can ->

> apt-get remove --purge PackageNameHere

Comment: Yeah, yeah, i know. Try guess what i was trying few last hours. This does not work.

Comment: @Garrom It appears that you think the user trying to help you, already knows what you have done.  Your lack of information can only leave everyone guessing what you have done.  We can be very specific with the resolution to the problem if you will add details of what you have done.  That's the only way we can identify what you might be missing, or what might be wrong with the commands you have executed.  If you performed, as @synaxis has suggested `sudo apt remove --purge firefox` show the exact command and the output in your question...

Comment: ... After you have run that command, please consider running (as @dsstorefile suggested) `dpkg -l firefox` to show the state the the purge has left.  There are other commands that the group will give you based on those outputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is really strange but I found a solution. If I disconnect from the internet while uninstalling the software, then the software does not get installed back.